# Mac App rejection due to Sandboxing Issue

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, accessibility-api

My Mac App has got rejected with following reason:

***"This version of the app does not only address bug fixes and new OS X feature adoption so it must implement sandboxing as of June 1, 2012"***

I am confused because in the previous version of the app which got submitted, I did not do anything related to sandboxing and it got approved. So, not sure why it got rejected this time.

When I asked the question to apple, they just keep repeating above message.

So, please guide me in this.

Let me know if you need more info to understand the question.

Comment: Does your app implement sandboxing? If not, what's wrong with the error message?

Comment: No, I have not implemented Sandboxing.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Can you please help me with my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Implement sandboxing?

Comment: You just need to setup valid sandbox values.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the previous version of your app was approved before June 1, 2012, when Apple started requiring all submissions for the App Store to be sandboxed. Since it was approved under the old rules, it's allowed to stay in the App Store despite the fact that it doesn't comply with the current rules.

However, if you want to update it, your updated version must comply with all current rules. In other words, in order for an update to be approved, it *must* be sandboxed.